# Copy folder with new name - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python...
How I copy a folder to other scr with a new name?
Example:

```
copy from
**c:/dir01
to
d:/dir02**
```

I tried:

```
shutil.copytree(path, pathDest1)
```

Comment: ``pathDest1`` is already the name of the new folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) is really clear about this:

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src, returning the
>   destination directory. The destination directory, named by dst, **must
>   not already exist.**

You can import `shutil`, and call copy tree.

```
import shutil

# Give the destination any name you wish.
copytree(path, pathDest1)
```